# Is there a layout in Xamarin forms for displaying it's children responsively based on their number?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, layout

Basically I need a layout in Xamarin forms for arranging a dynamic number of items ( 3 or 4).
In the case where there are 3 I want to keep them in the same row,but in the case of 4 I want to keep 2 items in every row.Is this possible?

Comment: [FlexLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/flex-layout)

Comment: Okay,but how can i explicitly set the 33% rule for each item in the case of 3  or the 50% rule in the case of 4?

Comment: Option 1: Bind width to a property and update it based on the screen size and list count. Option 2: if always 3 or 4, could use Grid and put two `item3` and set a data trigger for visibility.

Comment: @Shaw Though the problem with Grid is that for different cases i need to change the elements' rows and columns

Comment: Or you can set the grid position in code, [Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid).